Unable to use AgmCoreModule with angular 18 standalone component
I am using angular 18 with standalone components.
I have been trying to do google maps and address autocomplete integration with my component.
I have installed the AgmCoreModule and imported in my application config as is recommended for the standalone components.
Like this:
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
   importProvidersFrom(AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
    apiKey: '--------------------------',
    libraries: ['places']
  })),
  importProvidersFrom( MatGoogleMapsAutocompleteModule.forRoot('-------')),
]

Then in my component I am doing this:
@Component({
  selector: 'add-rv',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AnimateWithDelayDirective,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatGoogleMapsAutocompleteModule,
    AgmCoreModule <------------------------ // This gives an error (Component imports must be standalone components, directives, pipes, or must be NgModules.)  
  ],
  providers: [
    HttpClient,
    {
      provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
      useValue: { appearance: 'outline' },
    },
  ],
  templateUrl: './xx.component.html',
  styleUrl: './xx.component.scss',
})

Stuck!
If I remove the AgmCoreModule import from the component imports that none of the following HTML is recognized:
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [scrollwheel]="false" [zoom]="zoom">
     <agm-marker [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude"></agm-marker>
 </agm-map>

